# Youtube Channel Live Embed code no longer working

Tags: youtube, embed, channel

We've been embedding our live stream using this format URL in an iframe:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[channelid]`

It will automatically play the current live stream without needing the specific video id.

But now it says "Video unavailable"

Has Youtube changed anything? Is there any other method to doing this?

Note, we're completely verified for live streaming and embedding, and have made sure our live streams are set to public. We've also tried including various kinds of referrerpolicy in the iframe code. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this too.  It appears that YouTube changed this sometime recently and the /embed/live_stream is no longer functioning.

If you happen to be using WordPress this snippet will allow adding a shortcode that queries the YouTube Data API, gets video ID and adds the embed.  If the stream is not available a Maintenance message can be shown.  By default the video id is cahced in transients for 1 hour unless the stream is not live then it is only cached for 10 minutes.  This will reduce number of API calls and speed up the loading for most visitors of the site.

https://github.com/nmbgeek/wordpress-youtube-live-embed